# Download pdf from Firebase with URL

Tags: android, firebase, pdf, android-download-manager

I upload pdf in Storage Firebase with StorageReference and I saved the https link related to the file.
I do not know how to download the file with this link. 
Thw flow not enter in addOnSuccessListener. Why?
How can I do ?

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(urlResource);
        File localFile = File.createTempFile("example", ".pdf");
        storageRef.getFile(localFile)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Log.i("firebase ",";local tem file created  created ");
                    //  updateDb(timestamp,localFile.toString(),position);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    Log.i("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +exception.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Check the firebase storage permission once.

Comment: @Raj ok, now the flow enter in method addOnSuccessListener. But the the file is not downloaded. What should I add?

Comment: Whats the error show in OnFailure ?

Comment: Everything works. Thanks @Raj